# modprobe gives: “FATAL: <module> not found in directory” error

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, modprobe

I am running standard raspbian on Raspberry Pi-3.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I want to load dvb-core.ko but it fails with an error saying that this module is not under /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/ path, but it actually is under that path.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -r
4.14.79-v7+
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/kernel/drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb-core.ko 
/lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/kernel/drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb-core.ko
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ modprobe /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/kernel/drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb-core.ko 
modprobe: FATAL: Module /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/kernel/drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb-core.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+
```

No new message is displayed in `dmesg`. I am confused by this false reporting. I am sure there is an explanation for this, but can't figure it out.

Comment: I hit this same issue due to typing "modprobe name.ko" instead of "modprobe name". Perhaps this will help someone else.